# Kali (former BackTrack) installing dropbox

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

It might sound weird, but I've created a persistent (ext4) Kali live USB* and I'd like to install Dropbox on it (and maybe even Firefox).
Since it's based on a very old Ubuntu version I thought this would be a great place to ask this question.

- Kali is delivered with IceWeasel browser, but I'd rather use Firefox.
- I'm using Kali for testing purposes and I need the screenshots to be stored in my Dropbox, thus I want it to be installed on the persistent partition.

How can I install Dropbox (and Firefox) on a custom location? I've tried Apt-get/aptitude but I cannot choose a location as far as I can see.

Thanks in advance.

*I did not find a way to install Kali on an USB losing the "live" and "amnesia" part except the partition I create and pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> followed by typing "persistent"

The guide I've used was in Dutch so here's a snippet of the terminal command I've used to get the persistent working after using Gparted to format the drive:

> mkdir /mnt/usb
>
> mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb
>
> echo "/ union" >> /mnt/usb/persistence.conf
>
> umount /mnt/usb

Comment: Well, AFAIK Iceweasel is Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Kali does not include any software that is not easily available for any normal linux distro, so if its limitations are a hassle for you, you might want to consider switching to (e.g.) a normal recent ubuntu.

> How can I install Dropbox on a custom location?

You can download and compile dropbox [from source](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx), which should allow you to put it where ever you want.

> ...and Firefox

You can [download firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/#download-fx) pre-compiled -- be warned that link starts the download right away and detects your OS, so try it from Kali.  You should be able to run the `firefox` binary from inside the unpacked archive.  You were not specific about what you mean by "custom location", so I presume you know what you are doing and can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

For Installing Firefox :
First remove Iceweasel
**apt-get remove iceweasel**
Add a source to run **apt-get** to install it.

```
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.Sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list &gt; /dev/null
```

Import GPG keys

```
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.Sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list &gt; /dev/null
```

Update & Install Firefox

```
apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build*
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, .deb packages do not permit themselves to be installed to custom locations, as the binaries they include have been compiled expecting specific paths.

In addition to installing from source yourself or downloading pre-compiled binaries (as the two other answers suggest), there are also portable linux apps that you might try:

http://portablelinuxapps.org/