# How to make Dropbox keep the credential on Kali Rolling persistence Luke encrypted?

Tags: kali-linux, luks, dropbox, persistence

I'm using Kali Rolling distribution on USB stick with persistence Luke encrypted partition. Every think work great but I have only one problem:
Dropbox is constantly asking for credential at reboot (login and password).
This is imply that at each reboot Dropbox daemon is uploading or downloading files that it should not.

**How to make Dropbox keep the credential and not ask for login and password at each reboot?**

So far what I have done:

1. I installed and setup persistence luke encrypted partition using how to on http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence.
2. I installed and removed Dropbox over all the possible way: (deb package, ubuntu package, from source: see https://www.dropbox.com/install or [Kali (former BackTrack) installing dropbox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119496/kali-former-backtrack-installing-dropbox)).
3. I tried with a root and non root user.